# org-store-link with headline as description using CUSTOM_ID property?

Tags: org-mode

I recently upgraded my org-mode (to version 9.4.6) and now org-store-link/org-insert-link when used with a headline with a CUSTOM_ID property no longer inserts a link with the text of the headline as the link description. Instead, the generated description is the full pathname of the file containing the link and the custom id as a search target (delimited by "::").

I liked the old behavior; how can I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the previous code was for that, but I think they've added a separate `custom_id` in `org-store-link` (file `ol.el`).

You can see in `org-store-link` underneath the comment `;; Store a link using the CUSTOM_ID property.` in that function. This may not be a proper fix but you could simply change

```lisp
;; OTHER CODE

;; Store a link using the CUSTOM_ID property.
(setq custom-id (org-entry-get nil "CUSTOM_ID"))
(setq cpltxt
  (concat "file:"
.
.
```

to

```lisp
;; Store a link using the CUSTOM_ID property.
(setq custom-id (org-entry-get nil "CUSTOM_ID"))
(setq desc (org-link--normalize-string (org-get-heading t t t t)))
(setq cpltxt
  (concat "file:"
.
.
```

Basically setting `desc` as the current heading. There should be a better way but this works for me.